# OpenCL global worskize interpreted differently on Haswell & Kabylake iGPUs

Tags: opencl

Our kernel is initialized with:

```
size_t localWorkSize[1] = {1};
size_t globalWorkSize[2] = {60, 80};
```

The kernel implements a typical convolution on an image file.
It works fine on a machine with a Kabylake iGPU, but when executing it on Haswell or Bay Trail machines the global work size is interpreted as {60, 60} and therefore executes with a wrong NDRange.

On all systems our platform is **OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3**

Is this a known issue? Or is there a hardware-dependent limit to the global work size? There doesn't seem to be any info on that in the OpenCL Programming Guide.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you need to raise with the Beignet developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local work size and global work size must have the same dimension. See the documentation to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel:

```
local_work_size  Points to an array of work_dim unsigned values
global_work_size  Points to an array of work_dim unsigned values
```

So your code

```
size_t localWorkSize[1] = {1};
size_t globalWorkSize[2] = {60, 80};
```

If you enqueue a kernel with those and with workdim == 2, the driver will read that as

```
size_t localWorkSize[2] = {1, something};
size_t globalWorkSize[2] = {60, 80};
```

where something is whatever is on stack above localWorkSize. You need to do

```
size_t localWorkSize[2] = {1, 1};
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.