# Multidimensional Kernel launch in openCL not working

Tags: c, gpu, opencl

I am trying to launch openCL in 3 dimensions as follows:

```
size_t globalWorkSize[3] = {32, 3, 3};   
size_t localWorkSize[2] = {32, 32};   

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize,
                                                          0, NULL, NULL);
```

But only 32 threads are getting launched.

Also is there any way to find Cuda n openCL thread equivalence?

Can someone please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global work size determines how many tasks are launched. I.e. how many times will be the kernel function called in total.

Local work size partitions global work size into local groups so they can share memory and barriers.

The reason why only 32 threads are launched is because of the 1 in

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize,
                                                          0, NULL, NULL);
```

You specified the kernel is 1D, not 3D and the OpenCL will not look past the first values of those work sizes arrays. Apart from that, local work sizes must divide global work sizes - so all the local groups will have the same size. E.g the global `{32, 3, 3}` can have local sizes:

1. `{32,3,3}` which makes one local group = whole kernel can share memory.
2. `{32,1,1}` will make 3 local groups, each with size `{32,1,1}` .
3. In general any `{32/X,3/Y,3/Z}` grouping will work if and only if the numbers can be divided evenly and will form X*Y*Z local groups.

### CUDA vs. OpenCL work groups

OpenCL work item corresponds to a CUDA thread and OpenCL local work group is equivalent to a CUDA thread block. But the CUDA grid does not exactly correspond to the global work group because CUDA uses a bit different work organization.

The CUDA grid is composed of thread blocks and when calling the kernel one must specify the grid dimensions in terms of **thread blocks** and the block dimensions in terms of threads. But when calling an OpenCL kernel one must specify the global work group in terms of **work items not local groups**. This is the reason that global group size must be divisible by local group sizes (in all dimensions). Local groups are specified in terms of work items which again makes them equivalent to CUDA blocks.

**An example:**

CUDA kernel with a block of `{32,32,1}` threads organized into a grid of `{32,3,3}` thread blocks is equivalent to a local work group of `{32,32,1}`work items and the global work group of `{32*32,3*32,3*1}={1024,96,3}` work items.

**TLDR:**

local group = thread block

global group = grid * thread block

Comment: How would I launch Cuda like threads, anyidea?
So in this case I want 32,3,3 as grid dimension and each grid block having 32*32 threads.

Comment: @Nikhil Edited my answer, I hope that clears things up, feel free to ask more.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question here: [OpenCL global worskize interpreted differently on Haswell & Kabylake iGPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909805/opencl-global-worskize-interpreted-differently-on-haswell-kabylake-igpus)
GlobalWorkSize and localWorkSize apparently must have the same dimensions as implied by "work_dim" in https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html

Comment: How would I launch Cuda like threads, anyidea? So in this case I want 32,3,3 as grid dimension and each grid block having 32*32 threads.

Answer (score 0):

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, /*this is the number os dimensions: */ 3, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Just take care that the result of multiplication of the size of each of all dimensions must be equal to the total number of threads you want, and take care that the result of multiplication of the size of each of all workgroup dimensions must be equal to the number of threads in that workgroup you want.

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, because I never used more than one dimension.